# How can I fix PPA Failed to fetch errors while running apt-get update on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, updates, ppa

How can I fix the following errors I received during `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 14.04 so I can upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04?

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/etherum/ubuntu/dists/unity/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/etherum/ubuntu/dists/unity/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
```

I have tried everything I can find on here relating to this issue & don't understand what I may be doing wrong. I am fairly new to Ubuntu / Linux systems so please bear with me & try to help me.

Comment: You can ignore the warning ("`W:`") and follow [this steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/349837).

Answer (score 2):

Try launch "Software & update" utility, and disable these PPA`s on tab "Other"

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

Wasted a lot of time on this today but figure it out.

If you're getting ppa.launchpad.net timeout issues and using docker, here is how to fix it:

1. Add this line: `apt-get update --option Acquire::ForceIPv4=true --option Acquire::Retries=100 --option Acquire::http::Timeout=60`
2. Replace: `apt` with `apt-get` everywhere.
3. On the host machine run this `apt install dnsmasq`